# Overwriting a line in CSV file with C++

Tags: c++, csv, file-io

I'm writing a payroll program in c++ and need to be able to read lines in a file, do calculations, and then overwrite the read lines in the file.  IS there a function/way i can simply overwrite specific lines, insert new lines, add onto the end of an existing file?

Comment: Since you want to read and write to certain lines, you should look into reading and writing text files. Take a gander at fstream in the std library. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: This sounds like something that could be solved in a scripting language as well. Would this be a viable option?

Comment: I would recommend you use an SQL database instead if possible

Comment: Is an SQL database possible in c++? Im relatively new to programming in c++

Answer (score 2):

There are no C++ functionality to "insert" or "remove" text in a text-file. The only way to do that is to read the existing text in, and write out the modified text.

If the new text fits in the same space as the old one, all you need to do is to overwrite the existing text - and of course, you can always add extra spaces before/after a comma in a .CSV file, without it becoming part of the "field". But if the new data is longer, it definitely won't work to "overwrite in place".

Adding to the end is relatively easy by using the `ios_base::ate` modifier. But inserting in middle still involves basically reading until you find the relevant place, and then, if the new text is longer, you have to read all the following lines before you can write the new one(s) out.

Comment: so if i overwrite a specific line does it need to be the same length of characters?  or does it need to be the same length of strings (including values/commas)

Comment: The whole line will have to be the exact same number of characters, or either some "leftover" from the old line will remain in the file  (if the new line is shorter), or (a part of) the next line(s) will be overwritten (if the new line is longer than the old). In the typical case, I'd read every line into an array, and modify the relevant lines in that array [in other words `std::vector`], and write it back out again. [The array may be a string per line, or a vector of the type that each element is, of they are the same, or some sort of struct - depends on what your input is...]

Comment: ok thank you very much, this helps a lot.  One last question that would greatly help me, is it possible to create arrays based on the number of lines in my program?

Comment: If you use `std::vector`, you don't need to know the number of lines before you read the file. Just use `push_back` for each line you've read.